# Harder to search inside specific tag in the new navigation

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, new-nav

I'm used to search inside a specific tag by clicking the tag, then appending the key words in the search textbox. Saves me tons of typing.

However, when I now click a tag that's what happens:

> [image]

The search text box stay sad and empty, forcing me to type the tag in there. *shudder*

Can this please be changed so that it will populate the text box with the selected tag?

Comment: This has become more of an issue now that all [tag:tag] links are going to this same view.

Comment: @Kevin yes this is the issue, what you mean "has become **more** of an issue"?

Comment: I might have not noticed it yesterday, but any [`/questions/tagged/:tag`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) link is now going to this same view. Not just when you click a tag from the main page.

Comment: @Kevin well, each tag is a link to exactly this URL - and the new navigation design is changing that URL, since I search in tags a lot I noticed this pretty fast. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done and will be released in the next deployment.